# "Edit this page" or "View source option" for Jekyll blog post

Tags: r-markdown, jekyll, knitr, liquid

For my jekyll blog, I'm knitting Rmd to Md for the posts. At somewhere (preferably top), I want to programmatically add a link to view the source page (Rmd) hosted under `_sources` folder in top level directory.

Similar implementation can be found at https://yihui.org/en/about/ (at the left sidebar- `Edit this page` option)

Can this be done by some modification in custom `knit` command?
**OR**
Some `html-include` with `liquid` syntax should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working, so answering my own question

Well in Rmarkdown, we can access the current source file as `knitr::current_input()`.
This can be combined with the url of repository to get the full link to the source file. The best way is to create a new YAML entry as

```
RmdSource: '_source/`r knitr::current_input()`'
```

Now to programmatically add the link, either we can use `R` code with some liquid syntex at the top of the source file **OR** we can use `html-include` file inside the current layout file.

I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? This has the Github icon, and links to the repo on the github page. Without any reprex, or an example from you, this is the best I can do unless you give more details. Does Jekyll use YAML?

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. From the screenshot, I think you are using `blogdown`, because I'm not seeing the GitHub option at my side. My implementation is to simply convert `Rmd` to `Md` without using `blogdown` of site generation in RStudio. Anyway, I figured out a way and have answered my own question. Thanks for your input.